# Copy and Past MATLAB Character Array into Excel w/o Quotes

Tags: arrays, excel, matlab

I have a MATLAB character array that I am copying into an Excel spreadsheet, but whenever I paste it into the spreadsheet, the string in each cell starts and end with quotes. Is there any way to paste the array into Excel without the quotation marks? I know that I could just find and replace all of the quotation marks with nothing, but given that there are some quotes within the strings, it'd make thing a lot easier if there was a better work-around. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can't you just write the array to an excel spreadsheet?  Have you looked at `xlswrite`? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of the quotes by changing from a cell array to a char array. Using the tab character to separate the strings will make it paste into separate cells in excel by default.

Example:

```
A={'A' 'B' 'C'}; %Create the cell array.
cell2mat(strcat(A,{sprintf('\t')})) %Create a char array separated with tabs
```

Copy this output into excel

Answer (score 0):

My solution assumes a newer version of MATLAB (2016b, 2017a?) where the string class is available. Also, I'm assuming you have a cell array of strings (aka cellstr), not a character array although you can use `cellstr` to convert from to cellstr from a character array.

If this is the case you can do:

```
A = {'test' 'cheese' 'house of gold'};
B = string(A);
open B
```

In the variable editor then right-click and copy then paste into Excel.