# Display cell array without quotes - MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I have a cell array in Matlab named `outstr`. All of elements are strings. When I try to display my array, every string comes between quotation marks like this:

```
>> outstr

outstr =

'a'          'b'          'Fa'          'Fb'         'Xn'         'Fx'         'sign Fa*Fx'
'0.70000'    '0.90000'    '-0.19592'    '0.33887'    '0.77327'    '0.02896'    '-'         
'0.70000'    '0.77327'    '-0.19592'    '0.02896'    '0.76383'    '0.00206'    '-'         
'0.70000'    '0.76383'    '-0.19592'    '0.00206'    '0.76316'    '0.00012'    '-'         
'0.70000'    '0.76316'    '-0.19592'    '0.00012'    '0.76312'    '0.00000'    '-'
```

How do I display my array without quotations?

Comment: It's a little silly but you could convert it to a character array as suggested in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26322273/copy-and-past-matlab-character-array-into-excel-w-o-quotes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might meet the needs -

```
%// Input
outstr ={
'a'          'b'          'Fa'          'Fb'         'Xn'         'Fx'         'sign Fa*Fx'
'0.70000'    '0.90000'    '-0.19592'    '0.33887'    '0.77327'    '0.02896'    '-'         
'0.70000'    '0.77327'    '-0.19592'    '0.02896'    '0.76383'    '0.00206'    '-'         
'0.70000'    '0.76383'    '-0.19592'    '0.00206'    '0.76316'    '0.00012'    '-'         
'0.70000'    '0.76316'    '-0.19592'    '0.00012'    '0.76312'    '0.00000'    '-'  }

outstr1 = strcat(outstr,{'   '});  %// add whitespace

%// Convert to char array
outstr_char = char(outstr1{:})

%// Get size parameters
[m,n] = size(outstr1)
p = size(outstr_char,2)

%// Reshape + Permute Magic to create a 
%// char array "replica" of input cell array
out = reshape(permute(reshape(outstr_char.',p,m,[]),[1 3 2]),n*p,m).'

%// Display the char array
disp(out)
```

Sample run -

```
>> outstr
outstr = 
    'a'          'b'          'Fa'          'Fb'         'Xn'         'Fx'         'sign Fa*Fx'
    '0.70000'    '0.90000'    '-0.19592'    '0.33887'    '0.77327'    '0.02896'    '-'         
    '0.70000'    '0.77327'    '-0.19592'    '0.02896'    '0.76383'    '0.00206'    '-'         
    '0.70000'    '0.76383'    '-0.19592'    '0.00206'    '0.76316'    '0.00012'    '-'         
    '0.70000'    '0.76316'    '-0.19592'    '0.00012'    '0.76312'    '0.00000'    '-'         
>> disp(out)
a            b            Fa           Fb           Xn           Fx           sign Fa*Fx   
0.70000      0.90000      -0.19592     0.33887      0.77327      0.02896      -            
0.70000      0.77327      -0.19592     0.02896      0.76383      0.00206      -            
0.70000      0.76383      -0.19592     0.00206      0.76316      0.00012      -            
0.70000      0.76316      -0.19592     0.00012      0.76312      0.00000      -
```

Comment: You don't consider the spacing between columns. In this case you incidently get the spacing because upper right element is the longest. If you replace that one with a short string there won't be any space between third and fourth column.

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia Thanks for pointing that out! Edited with one additional line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you want the spacing between columns to be 3 whitespaces:

```
G = {};
for k=1:size(outstr, 2)
    G{k} = char(strcat(outstr(:,k), {'   '}));
end

result = cat(2, G{:});
```

This iterates over columns, adds extra spaces to the end of each element and converts them to character array and then in the end concatenated them together.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short solution:

```
sprintf('%s\n',string(outstr))
```